# How could I charge data in a table from another ones using PL/SQL procedures periodically?

Tags: oracle, plsql, insert, procedure

I want to insert data in a table from another 2 different tables using a PL/SQL, and I want it to be executed periodically (imagin weekly, for example) to be inserting new data.

Imagin that I have a table "Table1" which has columns named "name" and "id"; and another one "Table2" which has columns named "temperature" and "id", where the "id" is the column they have in common. On the other side, I want to insert thos data in a table "Table3" which has 3 columns named "id", "name" and "temperature".

How could I do it with a PLSQL procedure that executes periodically (weekly)?

Thank you so much!

Comment: I am working with Oracle.

Comment: Have a look at [DBMS_SCHEDULER](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm) and maybe [materialized views](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_6002.htm). btw you might want to lose the `MySQL` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a procedure and have it executed weekly, or whenever you need, by creating a job that calls the procedure.
[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schedadmin006.htm#i1009099) you find some examples.